# Holomorphic function on $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ has to be $\mathcal{C}^\infty (D)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm confused about this, in my notes I have the following:

---

Theorem: Let $f$ be holomorphic inside and on the boundary ($C$, itself a contour) of a simply connected region $D$. Then $\oint_Cf(z)dz=0$.

Proof:

Assuming that $f'$ is continuous in $D$ and on $C$,...

---

Now I always thought that a holomorphic function on $D$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty(D)$. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes. Probably at this point in your notes this has not yet been established.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing that up. As a non-maths student, I have to constantly deal with the math courses being taught less than rigorously leading to such chestnuts. In fact, this result doesn't seem to be established at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard assumption in this context is that $f$ is holomorphic in $D$ (which is open, so doesn't include the boundary) and continuous on its closure $\overline{D}$.  It doesn't have to be differentiable on the boundary.